# ssh config files and Ansible inventory

Tags: ssh, ansible, ansible-inventory

I have several remote servers to which I connect using SSH (host information gathered from ssh config files).

```
Host node1
  HostName 192.168.0.1


Host node2
  HostName 192.168.0.2


Host node3
  HostName 192.168.0.3
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa


Host node4
  HostName 192.168.0.4
  Port 9900
  User joe
```

On the other hand I use Ansible playbooks (host information from local inventory file) to provision servers.

```
[nginx_servers]
node1 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.0.1
node2 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.0.2

[webservers]
node3 ansible_host=192.168.0.3 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/id_rsa
node4 ansible_host=192.168.0.4 ansible_port=9900 ansible_user=joe
```

As the number of servers is increasing very quickly, it's becoming quite difficult to keep both ssh config and Ansible inventory files aligned.
Is there any way to automate the alignment between ssh config and Ansible inventory files?

Another idea I was wondering about, is to force ssh to read host information directly from Ansible inventory instead of SSH config files.
Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: You could use Ansible to generate your ssh configuration files using the `template` module so that your inventory is the single source of truth.

Comment: That's what the [`template` module – Template a file out to a target host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) is for and shown in the [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#examples).

Comment: I upvoted and asked to reopen. Here is the [answer](https://gist.github.com/vbotka/4f062e72f3f457287319cf81b7aeca48).

Comment: But this is not about programming, does it not belong on Superuser

Comment: I actually don't really get it. If you maintain a `~/.ssh/config` file with server nicknames and corresponding hostnames/ips, you just have to use those names in your ansible inventory without specifying `ansible_host` and ansible will obey the ssh configuration.